# How to make a Json parse without changes in Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, request, jsonparser

I make a  request to Go to Webinar API in Apps Script and the response is something like this:

```
{"joinUrl":"https://example.com","asset":true,"registrantKey":3669516009270899211,"status":"APPROVED"}
```

When I make a JSON.parse i get something like this:

```
{joinUrl=https://example.com, asset=true, registrantKey=3.6695160092708992E18, status=APPROVED}
```

The RegistrantKey changes, I dont know why.

**Thats my code:**

```
      try{
    var resp =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
    var json=JSON.parse(resp);
    return json
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err);
    return err;
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

I think that the reason of your issue is that `3669516009270899211` of `"registrantKey":3669516009270899211` is used as the number. In Javascript, the maximum integer value is `9007199254740991`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) So when `3669516009270899211` is converted to the number, it becomes `3.6695160092708992E18` and when this is converted to the string, it becomes `3669516009270899000`.

So in this case, as one of several workaround, how about enclosing `3669516009270899211` by the double quotes like `"registrantKey":"3669516009270899211"`? By this, `"3669516009270899211"` is used ad the string, and you can retrieve the value of `3669516009270899211`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

From:

```
var resp =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
var json=JSON.parse(resp);
return json
```

To:

```
var resp =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

resp = resp.getContentText().replace(/registrantKey":(\d.+),/, "registrantKey\":\"$1\",");  // Added

var json=JSON.parse(resp);
return json
```

#### Note:

- As the test script, you can also use the following script.

  ```
  var str = '{"joinUrl":"https://example.com","asset":true,"registrantKey":3669516009270899211,"status":"APPROVED"}';
  str = str.replace(/registrantKey":(\d.+),/, "registrantKey\":\"$1\",");
  var obj = JSON.parse(str);
  Logger.log(obj)
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Julio Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.